# php script to convert .png to .icns for mac os

Tags: php, image, gd

I am looking for php script that convert .png file to .icns file for mac.

Thanks.

Comment: Google? http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php+convert+img+to+icns&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Thanks. I have already search on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently imagemagick does not support icns out of the box (I am sure I used it before, but maybe with some additional library? Cannot remember)

However, just tested the little Linux too [icnsutils](http://icns.sourceforge.net/). It does not have PHP-bindings, so you will need to issue a system call (the horror)

Be vary wary of using variables whom you cannot entirely trust, in system calls. :)

Comment: yes. My colleague already implemented this way. He used linux script (.sh file). I thought if there is php script to do this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) if available:

```
$im = new imagick( '/path/to/file.png' ); 


$im->setCompressionQuality(100);
$im->setImageFormat('icns');

$im->writeImage('/path/to/new/file.icns');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Find out if you have imagemagick, with [phpinfo](http://nl.php.net/phpinfo)

Comment: Thank you very much @berkes. Currently I don't have imagemagick installed.
I am trying to install it but facing some problem. I am using xampp.

Comment: xampp comes with php_gd shipped, afaik. So you may be able to use that. The code will be very different from above, though.

Comment: I have tried above code but no success. Actually, imagick doesn't support "icns" format.